# texImage2D: width or height out of range, chrome 24

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I just started looking into the good stuff Three.js has to offer.

Now while trying to render a sphere with a texture I run into a problem.

I created a photosphere [image](http://www.in2systems.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/PANO_20121214_103159_extraklein.jpg) and tried to load it onto a sphere.

I am using the WebGL renderer build into Three.js (got the latest zip from GIThub).

Two things are puzzeling me:

1. The sphere including texture is rendered perfectly in both FF and Safari, but not in Chrome (24.0.1312.52).
2. When I try another picture, from the example of @kennydude on [github](https://github.com/kennydude/photosphere), it does work in all three tested browsers.

The only sign of something going wrong in Chrome I get is this warning:

WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range

My script is completely based on the example of @kennydude. I traced the error all the way back into the Three.js file r. 55 on line 25330. That is as far as I can get.

To get webGL running in Chrome I disabled the blacklist (my GPU appeared on that list).

Any ideas? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: btw you can try the faulty image on http://www.in2systems.nl/diensten/

Comment: That message means the texture is larger than the GPU supports safely. Some GPU drivers have bugs when textures are too large. You can check the maximum size allowed by calling `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)`. If the texture you want to load is too large consider creating a canvas, draw the image into the canvas to resize it, then make a texture from the canvas.

Comment: The image was indeed larger than the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE of 4096 in my browser. I will apply resizing to tackle that problem. Cheers gman!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try resizing the image to a power of two size like 4096x1024.

Comment: Cheers, that was the trick. I just had to set the width to a power of 2 size and set the height according to the original ratio. Thanks!!!